# Is Kafka transaction API only for producer?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is Kafka transaction API only for producer?

For example, I have an input topic ***A***.

messages are consumed from A, processed and then processed messages are sent to output topics ***B1*** and ***B2***.
Using transactional API, we can send messages to B1 and B2 together. all or nothing. It works great. I see no issues.

But what about committing/acknowledging A? will it be committed as part of transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding from this [confluent-article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/), it depends on whether committing the offset on the consumed message is carried out or not yet, if it is done, then it will be part of the transactions `read-process-write`, if not then it is not part of it.

Qouting from the article

> First, let’s consider what an atomic read-process-write cycle means. In a nutshell, it means that if an application consumes a message A at offset X of some topic-partition tp0, and writes message B to topic-partition tp1 after doing some processing on message A such that B = F(A), then the read-process-write cycle is atomic only if messages A and B are considered successfully consumed and published together, or not at all.

> Now, the message A will be considered consumed from topic-partition tp0 only when its offset X is marked as consumed. Marking an offset as consumed is called committing an offset. In Kafka, we record offset commits by writing to an internal Kafka topic called the offsets topic. A message is considered consumed only when its offset is committed to the offsets topic.

> Thus since an offset commit is just another write to a Kafka topic, and since a message is considered consumed only when its offset is committed, atomic writes across multiple topics and partitions also enable atomic read-process-write cycles: the commit of the offset X to the offsets topic and the write of message B to tp1 will be part of a single transaction, and hence atomic.

> Reading Transactional Messages
> Now, let’s turn our attention to the guarantees provided when reading messages written as part of a transaction.

> The Kafka consumer will only deliver transactional messages to the application if the transaction was actually committed. Put another way, the consumer will not deliver transactional messages which are part of an open transaction, and nor will it deliver messages which are part of an aborted transaction.